# Remove matrix rows if value below predefined threshold

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a 2 column matrix of values read from a .txt File. I am now trying to write a loop which iterates over every row in the matrix, and removes every row, where the value in the second column is below this threshold value.

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to be working like I expected:

```
for i = 1:size(full_matrix,2)
    if full_matrix(i,2) < min_value;
        full_matrix(i,:) = [];
    end
end
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: The code seems fine, I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. Can you give us some examples and expected results? The code above will remove the rows of the matrix where the second column value is below the set threshold.

If you remove the column, however, you will lose the *entire* second column of the matrix - I believe that is not what you want.

Comment: You don't need a for loop: `full_matrix(full_matrix(:,2)<min_val,:) = []`

Comment: Thank you for your help! The second comment worked - I'm also not sure why my code wasn't working... When I ran it would write a variable i=2 to the workspace, and remove the top two rows from the matrix

Comment: Your code wasn't working because the `for` loop was trying to iterate over all the lines of `full_matrix`, but unfortunately during the loop you were deleting lines, so then comes a point when the for loop is trying to read lines which don't exist anymore. You could correct it by simply remembering the indices of the lines to remove in the loop, and only removing the lines once out of the loop. But the neatest solution is to use vectorized method like @rinkert gave you in comment above.